# How to use use data anonymization with mysql database

Tags: python, privacy, anonymity

I will describe this. “IVM” stands for Intelligent Vacancy Manager which is our system. We are going to use MySQL database and we are going to store extracted data from CVs. It is a web-based application. Let’s say you’re the company.

When a company registers to the system, the company can upload their job vacancies to the system. So what the system does is it matches the CVs which is in a database that uploaded by Jobseekers. What I want to do is, when sending the Cvs to the companies, I want to use data anonymization. As just a part of the name, Hidden NIC, Address and Telephone Number is enough. I have to use python for that. What I feel is the database is just there with normal data (without anonymized). I feel is when sending the CVs to the company, in the middle my python script for anonymization should execute. So it doesn’t affect the database. Because when the company pay us and request the original CV, we can just execute the normal query to send the original Cv without hiding data.

I want my python script to do, when suggesting CVs, just affect the Name, NIC, Address, Telephone number.
Apart from that, I am asked to use the Kerberos authentication protocol to authorize users to the system.

I hope now you have somewhat knowledge of what I am going to do. if you have any idea on this thing please guide me and I would really grateful to you. I will be waiting for a reply soo :)

I have to do this as my university project. So I would like to hear all your suggestions.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Anonymization is difficult, especially when you're talking about something as comprehensively identifying as a CV. To keep things secret yet searchable in your DB, you need some Python equivalent of a library like [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet).

Comment: Cvs data are extracted and stored in a mysql db. So I want to know when we send the Cv data to the company as a new format, I want to intercept using a python script to hide the email, telephone , name and address in those data in the middle of the sending data without affecting the db.